# issue in dialog box--getting a blank record inserted in the table with each edit

Tags: reactjs

I have this working code in reactjs.The code takes up input from the user and adds it to the table.That is going fine.But when i need to edit the record,its being edited also correctly and inserted in the table as well,but the issue is that with each insertion ,I am getting a blank record also inserted in the table.Can anyone tell me why is the insertion of blank record happening with each edit.Here is the code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';


class FormDialog extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {edit: false,
      view: true,
      students: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' },
        { id: 5, name: 'kiwi', age: 20, email: 'kiwi@email.com' }
     ],
    };
  }
  handleClose(){
    this.setState({view:!this.state.view})
  }
  onDeleteHandle() {let id = arguments[0];
    this.setState({students:this.state.students.filter(item => {if (item.id !== id)
       {return item;}})});}


onEditHandle(event) 
{     
this.setState({edit:true,id: arguments[0],name:arguments[1],age:arguments[2],email:arguments[3]});

}
onUpdateHandle(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({students: this.state.students.map(item => {
    if (item.id === this.state.id){
      item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;        
      item['name']=event.target.updatedItem1.value;
      item['age']=event.target.updatedItem2.value;
      item['email']=event.target.updatedItem3.value;
    }return item;})})
    this.setState({edit: false});
}

renderEditForm() {
  if (this.state.edit) {
  return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
  <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
  <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
  <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
  <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
  <button className="update-add-item">Update</button> 
  </form>    }  }

  onSubmitHandle(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({students: [...this.state.students, {id:event.target.id.value,name: event.target.item.value,age:event.target.xyz.value,email:event.target.email.value}]  })
      event.target.item.value = '';
      event.target.id.value = parseInt(event.target.id.value)+parseInt(1);
      event.target.email.value = '';
      event.target.xyz.value = '';
    }; 


      render() {

      return (
        <div> 
          <Dialog  fullWidth open={this.state.view} onClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>
            <DialogTitle>Sign Up Provide Details</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>

              <DialogContentText>
                <div>
              {this.renderEditForm()}
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)}>

             <label >ID</label>
                   <input type="number"  name="id" className="item"  />
                 <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="item" className="item"  />
                   <label>age</label>
                   <input type="number" name="xyz" className="item"  />
                   <label>email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" className="item"  />  
                   <button className="btn-add-item">Add</button>                 
                   <table>{this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td>

                    <button onClick={this.onEditHandle.bind(this,abc.id,abc.name,abc.age,abc.email)}>Edit</button>
                    </tr>))}</table>
                    </form>
                    </div>

                </DialogContentText>

                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>


                </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>         


          </div>

      );

  }
}

export default FormDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

When inserting functions for props use the format

```
onSubmit={(e)=>whateverFunction(e)}
```

This way the function won't be called when there is a render, only when the event is trigered.

Comment: I did the following changes but the issue still persists.<form onSubmit={(event)=>this.onSubmitHandle(event)}>

Comment: Then what you can do is check for data before updating to prevent blanks

So something like `if(!value)return;`

this will make update if there is any value before updating